# Category title display issue in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the code below for a category in WordPress. It displays the name of the category when I want it to be displaying the title of the post. How do I get it to display the title of the post proper.

```
<? query_posts('category_name=implants');
?>
<h3><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h3>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : 

the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content( __('Read the 

rest of this page »', 'template')); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Do not use query_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) unless your intention is to modify the
   default Wordpress Loop. Use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead for standard Wordpress
   queries.
2. Look at your code. You're calling single_cat_title(). It means
   exactly what it looks like: You're pulling the title of the queried
   category. You want to call the_title() to grab the post title.
3. Not as important as the above, but your opening tag is <? rather
   than <?php. You should make it a habit of specifying your server-side language to avoid potential future problems, even though it might not be initially apparent.

Here's what your revised loop should look like:

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query('category_name=implants');
if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php
the_content( __('Read the rest of this page »', 'template'));
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Maiorano Thanks for the answer and correction, It worked perfectly.